# How do I get the installed antivirus software and firewall programmatically?

Tags: c#, vb.net, security, firewall, antivirus

How can I get information about the antivirus software and firewall software that is installed on a Windows computer?

Comment: Pretend than you're on Jeopardy; reformulate this as a question with a specific problem to be solved, and post your solution as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ManagementObjectSearcher to obtain this information.

```
 Public Function GetAntivirus() As String
    Try
        Dim data As String = String.Empty
        For Each firewall As ManagementObject In New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\SecurityCenter" & IIf(My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("XP"), "", "2").ToString, "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct").Get
            data &= firewall("displayName").ToString
        Next
        If Not data = String.Empty Then
            Return data
        Else
            Return "No Antivirus"
        End If

    Catch
        Return "No Antivirus"
    End Try

End Function

Public Function GetFirewall() As String
    Try

            Dim data As String = String.Empty
            For Each firewall As ManagementObject In New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\SecurityCenter" & IIf(My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("XP"), "", "2").ToString, "SELECT * FROM FirewallProduct").Get
                Data &= firewall("displayName").ToString
            Next
        If Not data = String.Empty Then
            Return data
        Else
            Return "No Firewall"
        End If
        Catch
            Return "No Firewall"
        End Try

End Function
```